# Double cout failure during debug

Tags: c++

I getting this strange...strangeness when I try to debug this code segment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "windows.h"
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

double frameCount;

int main()    
{
    frameCount = 18;
    std::cout << frameCount << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles for no problem. It even runs properly but if I debug it line-by-line the program seizes up when I try to output "frameCount" to the console;

```
    std::cout << frameCount << std::endl;
```

The issue is resolved by changing "frameCount" to an int. Here is the debugger result from the line.

```
[debug]> next
[debug]0x004496f4 in std::ostream::operator<<(double) ()
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:

In std::ostream::operator<<(double) () ()

[debug]> info locals
[debug]No symbol table info available.
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> info args
[debug]No symbol table info available.
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> whatis frameCount
[debug]type = double
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> output frameCount
[debug]1.8>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> bt 30
[debug]#0  0x004496f4 in std::ostream::operator<<(double) ()
[debug]#1  0x004165ae in __do_global_ctors ()
[debug]#2  0x004010fd in __mingw_CRTStartup ()
[debug]#3  0x00000001 in ?? ()
[debug]#4  0x7ffde000 in ?? ()
[debug]#5  0x7757ad1f in ?? ()
[debug]#6  0x7757acea in ?? ()
[debug]#7  0x00000000 in ?? ()
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
```

Comment: This isn't the problem, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 1):

For your purpose, you don't need

```
#include <conio.h>
#include "windows.h"
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
```

above headers. without these headers. It seems okay.

Comment: The code example I provided was/is part of a larger program. I left all the includes in case one of them is somehow skewing the results.